# How to get FileID from Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can I get FileID from Sharepoint. The fileID that I'm looking for is the Guid that we required to pass in to the 'GetFileById' method. For example

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://myserver");    
var fileGuid = new Guid("D51C440B-4F52-4005-90BE-BDC42E850975");
var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileById(fileGuid);
```

Additionally, I'm using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client from Nuget (version: 14.0.4762.1000) in a .NET console app to access sharepoint . I don't see the method 'GetFileById' anymore in this dll and due to this I'm using the below code to retrieve the sharepoint file object

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(new Uri("http://myserver")))
            {
                try
                {
                    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                    context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                  
                    Web web = context.Web;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File doc = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docURL);

                    context.Load(doc, d => d.Name, d => d.Exists, d => d.ListItemAllFields);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
```

How can I get fileID(Guid) from the above code snippet ? I tried using ListItemAllFields["_dlc_DocId"] but that is not fileID(Guid) that I'm looking for.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: can you please ensure that the Document ID feature is enabled on the Site Collection that you are looking into ?
https://morgantechspace.com/2021/10/how-to-enable-document-id-feature-in-sharepoint-online.html#:~:text=View%20and%20Get%20SharePoint%20File%20URL%20with%20Document%20ID,-You%20can%20view&text=Navigate%20to%20the%20document%20library%2C%20select%20the%20required%20document%2C%20and,option%20to%20copy%20the%20URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ListItemAllFields["UniqueId"] to get the sharepoint FileID (Guid). See the below code

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(new Uri("http://myserver")))
            {
                try
                {
                    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                    context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                  
                    Web web = context.Web;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File doc = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docURL);

                    context.Load(doc, d => d.Name, d => d.Exists, d => d.ListItemAllFields);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(doc.ListItemAllFields["UniqueId"]);
                }
            }
```